# while running test class for apex I face this problem

Tags: unit-test

```
public class AddRowtocontact {
    Public List<contact> conlist{set;get;}
    Public List<Account> acclist{set;get;}
   // Public integer rownum{set;get;}

    Public AddRowtocontact(){

        conlist= new List<Contact>();
       acclist=new List<Account>();
         addrow();
        rowAccount();

    }
    Public void addrow(){
        Contact c=new Contact();
        conlist.add(c);
    }


    Public pagereference save(){
       upsert conlist;
         Upsert acclist;
        pagereference pr=new pagereference('https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/AddRowtocontact?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1');
         return pr;
    }

    Public void remove(){
      integer row= (integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('del'))); 
        if(row>1){
            conlist.remove(row-1);
        }

    }
    Public Void rowAccount(){
        Account a=new Account();
        acclist.add(a);
    } 
    Public void removerow(){
        integer row= (integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('dell'))); 
        if(row>1 ){
             acclist.remove(row-1);
        }

    }


}
```

---

```
// test class//
@istest
public class AddRowtocontactTestclass {
    static testmethod void teststart(){

            /*Account testAccount = new Account();
            testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
            insert testAccount;*/
        contact con=new Contact();
        con.LastName='raj';
        insert con;
        con.LastName='jjj';
        upsert con;

        test.startTest();
       /* PageReference pageR = Page.AddRowtocontact; // Add your VF page Name here
     pageR.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(testAccount.Id));
         Test.setCurrentPage(pageR);*/
         PageReference pageRef = Page.AddRowtocontact; // Add your VF page Name here
     pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(con.Id));
         Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);



        AddRowtocontact obj=new AddRowtocontact();
        obj.addrow();
        obj.save();
        obj.remove();
        obj.rowAccount();
        obj.removerow();

       test.stopTest(); 

    }


}
```

> //error// System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row
>   0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [LastName]: [LastName]

Comment: Your code will clear all entered contact data every time you add a row. Is that what you want? If so no point in adding rows

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you are adding a new instance in `addRow` method while in `save` you are trying to Save that.

As last name is required field so you need to fill that in your test class.

So your code will be

```
obj.addrow();
conlist[0].LastName = 'Test';//fill all other required fields as well
obj.save();
```

Comment: It'd make more sense to fix the real method so that it doesn't fail when it's used, instead of just making the test pass. but yeah this is the problem the solution will depend on what that class is actually trying to do, which isn't immediately apparent (to me at least)

Comment: @Aequitas In this type of use case we have one VF page where we fill the required fields and then click on save.  So AFAIK we need to manually enter all required data in test class to make it work.